# Bug in Kohana 3 ORM?

Tags: orm, kohana-3, kohana-orm

Sorry to ask all these questions about Kohana. They usually get ignored. I think I just found a bug. I'm making a join between two tables that are not directly related.

```
$results = ORM::factory('foo')->join("bar")->on("foo.foreign_id", "=", "bar.id");
```

This generates a query that does not resolve the table names explicitly:

```
SELECT * FROM `foo` JOIN `bar` ON (`foo`.`foreign_id` = `bar`.`id`)
```

Which gives (in phpMyAdmin) a table that looks like this:

```
id    time          foreign_id      blah_int    id  baz
4     1291851245    3           0               3   52501504
```

Notice there are two `id` columns, one for the `foo` table and one for `bar`. This is a real problem. Because now, in my results, if I loop through...

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result->id;    // prints 3!!!
}
```

Because my results should be `foo` objects, I expect to get an id of 4, but it's giving me 3 because of the join. Is this a bug in the ORM library? Should I be using a different method to restrict my results from the query? I really don't want to do two separate queries where I load all the `bar`s id's, and then load my `foo`s that way, but it looks like I have to.

Comment: Have you tried ORM relations (http://kohanaframework.org/guide/tutorials.orm)? Something like foreach($foo->bars as $bar) {...}

Comment: The tables aren't related, except indirectly. They share a relationship with another table. So my alternative is to load ids from the table in common first, but I would rather not.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the Database object to build raw queries, not ORM, like this:

```
$results = DB::select()->from('foo')->join('bar')->on("foo.foreign_id", "=", "bar.id")->execute();
```

You will need to specific some column aliases however to make your query work unless you use ORM as it was intended.

**Using ORM**

If you want to use ORM, you need to define the relationships in your model. You mention that they share a relationship with another table so in your case you could use a has many through relationship like this:

```
protected $_has_many = array(
    'bars' => array('model' => 'bar', 'through' => 'other_table', 'foreign_key' => 'foreign_id'),
    );
```

Although your example as given suggests that a straight has_many relationship would work:

```
protected $_has_many = array(
    'bars' => array('model' => 'bar','foreign_key' => 'foreign_id'),
    );
```

This would allow you to access all of the bars using a statement like

```
$bars = $results->bars->find_all();
foreach($bars as $bar)
{
    echo $bar->id; // should echo 4, assuming one record in bars with id 4
}
```

The [Kohana 3.1 ORM Reference Guide](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/orm/relationships) is good place to start if you want to learn more about ORM and relationships

**Using the Kohana database object and query builder**

If you prefer ad hoc queries and are doing joins using the query builder you will likely have colliding column names regardless if you are using Kohana or just raw queries (pop "SELECT * FROM `foo` JOIN `bar` ON (`foo`.`foreign_id` = `bar`.`id`)" into MySQL and you will get the exact same result).

Kohana, just like MySQL allows you to define column aliases for precisely this reason. (See [here for more information](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/database/query/builder#select-as-column-aliases))

Rewrite your query as follows:

```
$results = DB::select('id', 'time', 'foreign_id', array('bar.id', 'bar_id'), 'baz')->from('foo')->join("bar")->on("foo.foreign_id", "=", "bar.id")->execute();
```

This will return:

```
id    time          foreign_id      blah_int    bar_id   baz
4     1291851245    3               0           3        52501504
```